# Selecting rows where values of two columns are same in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I would to have your guidance on a type of data selection in ArcGIS. I would like to select the rows of a feature "where the values of two columns are the same". as a standard approach there is no such a thing in ArcGIS and I am wondering how it is possible to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Open the attibute table, and write "Field_A" = "Field_B".

In the example below I put `"Ip" = "Jp"`:

[image]

Comment: I found the problem, the data types were not the same and now it is working.thank you !